# Regarding spin Hall effect and Thomas precession

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, quantum-spin

I was reading about Mathison–Papapetrou–Dixon (MPD) equations which describe the motion of massive spinning particles. I am wondering if these sets of equations are just a quantum version of the classical Thomas precession or not?
The reason why I believe so is that Thomas precession gives us evolution of spin 4-vector. And using the fact that the inner product of 4-velocity and 4-spin is zero, we can differentiate the inner product to determine the evolution of 4-velocity, and hence of the 4-wave vector (because both are tangent vectors to the world line of the particle and hence differ by a scalar factor). And this is precisely the information that the MPD equation gives. Is my analysis correct or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The MPD equations are purely classical and have nothing to do with quantum mechanics.

In terms of effects on the dynamics the MPD equations encompass more than just Thomas precession, which is a purely flat space relativistic effect. In addition the MPD equations capture the effects of space time curvature on the spin, corrections to the trajectory due to the spin, and corrections to the motion of the spin due to the spin.

Comment: Hey! Thomas precession can be written in a general relativistic lingo by replacing all partial derivatives with covariant derivatives. Is that what MPD equation is?

Comment: No the MPD equations are more than just that.

Comment: Well, that is what my question is! I checked the Wikipedia page and they have described MPD equations as a set of 2 equations, one for the time evolution of spin, and the other one for the time-evolution of the wave-vector. It will be great if you can explain the difference.